# Function and program instruction memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I have been searching for these questions but can't find any.

1) Is the function declaration and definition, itself stored in the stack?
I know their variables are but what about the function itself?

2) What does Program instruction/text region refer to in the segment of memory for a process? Examples?

Answer (score 2):

No. The stack is for storing the function-call order and context, as you call and return from functions. This also includes these functions' local variables. The stack is in a (preferably non-executable) read-write data section of memory.

The code itself for the entire program is (usually) in the `.text` section, which is located in read-only executable memory.

If you're on Linux, check out the `readelf` utility which will tell you all about how your ELF executable is going to be laid out when loaded into memory.

If you're on Windows PE Explorer will do something similar, although it is outdated, not free, and doesn't support 64-bit (PE32 Plus) executables.

Comment: .text region as in the Program instruction / text region? Which is at the bottom of the process memory (lowest)?

Comment: Yes, your program's code (the binary machine instructions).  What you ask is implementation-specific. Check out some compiled executables to see how they are usually laid out.

Answer (score 1):

Function declsrations and definitions are syntactic constructs, like a comma or a pair of brackets. They only exist in the source code, and not stored anywhere.

A function, on the other hand, is something that exists at run time and has an address. It is not specified where thst address is. As far as C is concerned, fumctions and data belong to totally different addresss spaces. Their addresses cannot be mixed. So you cannot even ask whether it's on the stack or not, the question is ill-defined.

C has no notion of program instruction or segment or process, so it makes no sense to talk about them in the context of C either. You need to specify your architecturr and OS in order to be able to talk about them.

Comment: Unless you compile with `-g` :-)